# JSP class not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp

Tags: java, jsp

When I start my Struts 2 Application, I got a 500 code. Here's the stack.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getDispatcherType()` (of class ServletRequest) was added to the Servlet API in version 3.0.  So it seems that you are the Tomcat you are running is version 6.x or earlier which uses a Servlet API before 3.0, hence the method is unknown. Inside your IDE you apparently compile against the 3.0 version of the Servlet API.

You must use Tomcat 7+ to use Servlet API 3.0 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `login.jsp` has some compilation error. Try looking into that. Also, post the code here.

Comment: But the IDE report no compilation error. I get the ClassNotFound only when  trying to access the jsp.

Comment: Post the code & complete stack trace (I think you missed the root cause section of trace).

Comment: 'An error occurred at line: [63] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\guoli\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_Typle_2\work\Catalina\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\login_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest'

Comment: Did I miss some jars?

Comment: Right, so actually it is saying that you have used something incorrect in your jsp file (which eventually converted to a Java servlet).

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pco/Init.jsp"%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
NMTC Automation Summary
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<H2>
Network Management Task Controller<br>
Administration Tool<br>
</H2>
<table>
<% if (userAuthorization.isPrincipalInRole((String)session.getAttribute("SecPTUserIDname_&"), "pco") ||
      userAuthorization.isPrincipalInRole((String)session.getAttribute("SecPTUserIDname_&"), "pcoview"))
   {
%>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="../pco/PCO.jsp?level=1">T1 PCO Automation</a></td></tr>
<%
   }
%>

<% if (userAuthorization.isPrincipalInRole((String)session.getAttribute("SecPTUserIDname_&"), "t3pco") ||
      userAuthorization.isPrincipalInRole((String)session.getAttribute("SecPTUserIDname_&"), "t3pcoview"))
   {
%>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="../t3pco/PCO.jsp?level=3">T3 PCO Automation</a></td></tr>
<% 
     }
%>

<% if (userAuthorization.isPrincipalInRole((String)session.getAttribute("SecPTUserIDname_&"), "nise"))
   {
%>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="../nise/NISE.jsp">NISE</a></td></tr>
<%
   }
%>

<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="UserChangePasswd.jsp">Change Your Password</a></td></tr>

<% if (userAuthorization.isPrincipalInRole((String)session.getAttribute("SecPTUserIDname_&"), "admin"))
   {
%>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="../admin/PassAdmin.jsp">Administer User IDs</a></td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="../admin/PCORule.jsp">Administer PCO Automation Rule Table</a></td></tr>
<%
   }
%>

<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr align="center"><td><a href="../login.jsp?LogOut=true"><b>Logoff</b></a></td></tr>
</table>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.